# angular unsafe Urls

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have used Domsanitizer in my application to load dynamic video urls.
but autoplay(autoplay=1), disable related videos(rel=0) and more are not working with sanitizer.

- js file

  import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  ```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,) {}

  checkUrl(url) {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
  ```
- html file

  ```
  <iframe class="myVideoClass" [src]="checkUrl(item.videoUrl)" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
  ```

auto play and disable related videos are not working properly. if i remove sanitizer and give only the **src="https://..."** link it works perfectly. the issue is with sanitizer. is there any alternate path to use unsafe Urls. or what could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use just ?
[src]="item.videoUrl"

Angular will esacpe only quoutes, and will not break the template if there will be some invalid data.

Comment: not working.ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Comment: try using bypassSecurityTrustHtml or bypassSecurityTrustUrl instead of bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that ?

```
checkUrl(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)+&autoplay=1;
}
```